# mutate %>% case_when assigning values to incorrect columns and/or multiple columns

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, tidyverse, case, mutate

I have inherited a script that is way above my skill set and the person who created it, is no longer around.  I have noticed one thing wrong with the script that seems easy to fix (or so I thought).  I am comparing tree measurements between "CHKR" and all other people that are not "CHKR".  In other words for every tree there are measurements for CHKR and someone else. These measurements are placed into categories based on diameter, height, etc.

I want to place all measurements where CRU!=CHKR to be in the same category as CHKR. The yellow cells indicate the problems or things to look at.  For example STDPLT 23120656_400 TREE1, CRU=DUH has DBH values that fall in DBH_temp1, while CHKR has values that fall in DBHC_temp1.  I want to mutate DBHA, DBHB, DBHC values to be populated based on the CHKR values.

A second problem that I am encountering is that when CRU!= CHKR I am getting values entered into multiple columns. I am getting correct values for when CRU==CHKR

[image]

Here is what I would like to look like:
[image]

I have tried countless attempts of various case_when and ifelse.

This is the closest that I can get. The problem is for when CRU!=CHKR.  I am mutating several columns and placing values in the wrong columns.

```
ctre=ctre %>%
  group_by(STDPLT,TREE)%>%
  mutate(
    DBHA= case_when(
      CRU=="CHKR" & DBHA_temp1 == DBH ~ DBHA_temp1,
      CRU!="CHKR" ~ ifelse(DBHB_temp1 == DBH|DBHC_temp1 == DBH , DBH, NA)
    ),
    DBHB= case_when(
      CRU=="CHKR" & DBHB_temp1 == DBH ~ DBHB_temp1,
      CRU!="CHKR" ~ ifelse(DBHA_temp1 == DBH | DBHC_temp1 == DBH, DBH, NA)
    ),
    DBHC= case_when(
      CRU=="CHKR" & DBHC_temp1 == DBH ~ DBHC_temp1,
      CRU!="CHKR" ~ ifelse(DBHA_temp1 == DBH | DBHB_temp1 == DBH, DBH, NA)
    )
  )
```

```
ctre <- structure(list(STANDID = c(23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 
23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 
23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656), PLOT = c(400, 
400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 405, 405, 405, 405, 405, 405, 
405, 405), STDPLT = c(23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 
23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 
23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656, 23120656), CRU = c("DUH", 
"CHKR", "DUH", "CHKR", "DUH", "CHKR", "DUH", "CHKR", "DUH", "CHKR", 
"DUH", "CHKR", "DUH", "CHKR", "DUH", "CHKR"), TREE = c(1, 1, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), SP = c("DF", "DF", 
"DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", "DF", 
"DF", "DF", "WH"), DBH = c(9.5, 25.8, 9.8, 26.2, 15, 14.4, 12, 
11.4, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9), TOTHT = c(49, 
94, 49, 94, 52, 60, 52, 60, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 
103), BHA = c(100, 50, 100, 50, 44, 50, 44, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), DBHA_temp1 = c(9.5, NA, 9.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DBHB_temp1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, 
14.4, 12, 11.4, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9
), DBHC_temp1 = c(NA, 25.8, NA, 26.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without having access to your data. Please share the output of `dput(ctre)` in a separate code chunk in your question, if `ctre` is big, use `dput(head(ctre, 30))` instead. From looking at your code I'd also recommend not mixing `case_when()` and `ifelse()`, instead use `case_when()` only. The condition in the `ifelse()` statement seems to be inadequate.

Comment: one thing you can do that would be really helpful is comment your code, to tell us what you intend for it to do. Your code is doing exactly what it should do, given what you have written. The issue is that you want something else, and it's unclear what the rules you want are. I think some rubber duck debugging is in order

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one can create the desired output (note: if you only show the code and the data, without explaining what you actually want, it's impossible to know, and I'm forced into things like `DBHA = NA`:

```
ctre |>
  mutate(
    DBHA = NA,
    DBHB= DBHB_temp1,
    DBHC = ifelse(is.na(DBHA_temp1), DBHC_temp1, DBHA_temp1))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 16 × 15
    STANDID  PLOT   STDPLT CRU    TREE SP      DBH TOTHT   BHA DBHA_temp1
      <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 23120656   400 23120656 DUH       1 DF      9.5    49   100        9.5
 2 23120656   400 23120656 CHKR      1 DF     25.8    94    50       NA  
 3 23120656   400 23120656 DUH       2 DF      9.8    49   100        9.8
 4 23120656   400 23120656 CHKR      2 DF     26.2    94    50       NA  
 5 23120656   400 23120656 DUH       3 DF     15      52    44       NA  
 6 23120656   400 23120656 CHKR      3 DF     14.4    60    50       NA  
 7 23120656   400 23120656 DUH       4 DF     12      52    44       NA  
 8 23120656   400 23120656 CHKR      4 DF     11.4    60    55       NA  
 9 23120656   405 23120656 DUH       1 DF     14.9   103     0       NA  
10 23120656   405 23120656 CHKR      1 DF     14.9   103     0       NA  
11 23120656   405 23120656 DUH       2 DF     14.9   103     0       NA  
12 23120656   405 23120656 CHKR      2 DF     14.9   103     0       NA  
13 23120656   405 23120656 DUH       3 DF     14.9   103     0       NA  
14 23120656   405 23120656 CHKR      3 DF     14.9   103     0       NA  
15 23120656   405 23120656 DUH       4 DF     14.9   103     0       NA  
16 23120656   405 23120656 CHKR      4 WH     14.9   103     0       NA  
   DBHB_temp1 DBHC_temp1 DBHA   DBHB  DBHC
        <dbl>      <dbl> <lgl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1       NA         NA   NA     NA     9.5
 2       NA         25.8 NA     NA    25.8
 3       NA         NA   NA     NA     9.8
 4       NA         26.2 NA     NA    26.2
 5       15         NA   NA     15    NA  
 6       14.4       NA   NA     14.4  NA  
 7       12         NA   NA     12    NA  
 8       11.4       NA   NA     11.4  NA  
 9       14.9       NA   NA     14.9  NA  
10       14.9       NA   NA     14.9  NA  
11       14.9       NA   NA     14.9  NA  
12       14.9       NA   NA     14.9  NA  
13       14.9       NA   NA     14.9  NA  
14       14.9       NA   NA     14.9  NA  
15       14.9       NA   NA     14.9  NA  
16       14.9       NA   NA     14.9  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured it out.

First thing I did was assign CRU!= CHKR to all DBHA, DBHB,etc classes.

```
ctre=ctre %>% group_by(STDPLT, TREE) %>% mutate(
DBHA= case_when(
  CRU=="CHKR" & DBHA_temp1 == DBH ~ DBHA_temp1,
  CRU!="CHKR" ~ DBH,TRUE ~ NA
),
DBHB= case_when(
  CRU=="CHKR" & DBHB_temp1 == DBH ~ DBHB_temp1,
  CRU!="CHKR"  ~ DBH, TRUE ~ NA
),
DBHC= case_when(
  CRU=="CHKR" & DBHC_temp1 == DBH ~ DBHC_temp1,
  CRU!="CHKR" ~ DBH,TRUE ~ NA
)
```

*This is the part of the process that I could not figure out.
Then I assigned where CRU!= CHKR to the DBH class of CRU==CHKR

```
enter code here ctre=ctre %>% group_by(STDPLT, TREE) %>% mutate(
DBHA= case_when(
  CRU=="CHKR" & DBHA_temp1 == DBH ~ DBHA_temp1,
  CRU!="CHKR" &  DBHA[CRU == "CHKR"]~ DBH,TRUE ~ NA
),
DBHB= case_when(
  CRU=="CHKR" & DBHB_temp1 == DBH ~ DBHB_temp1,
  CRU!="CHKR" & DBHB[CRU == "CHKR"] ~ DBH, TRUE ~ NA
),
DBHC= case_when(
  CRU=="CHKR" & DBHC_temp1 == DBH ~ DBHC_temp1,
  CRU!="CHKR" & DBHC[CRU == "CHKR"]~ DBH,TRUE ~ NA
)
```

)

I am not 100% sure, but I believe the exact piece of code that solved my problem is CRU!="CHKR" &  DBHA[CRU == "CHKR"].  I think* that this saying "put all CRU not equal to CHKR into the DBHA class if CHKR is in DBHA.